# I want to know how I can get the content of a webservices RES secure with spring security from another application

Tags: java, spring, rest, web-services, webservice-client

I created a RES  webservices with spring and I secured with spring security
I want to know how I can get the content of a webservices  secure with spring security from another application .

Comment: what do you mean exactly? how did you secured them? By using OAuth2/OpenID? By Basic authentication?

Comment: HOW to Consume a RESTful Web Service in Java  and sending username and password in request

Answer (score 0):

HOW to Consume a RESTful Web Service in Java  and sending username and password in request